# Cocoa check for multiple file extensions in folder

Tags: cocoa, nsstring

I need to raise an Alert panel if a folder *does not* contain files with the extension strings in code below. The "input" textField contains the path string ... Can't get it to work ... Thanks for help.

```
 NSString * filePath = [input stringValue];
 NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

 NSString *theFolder= [fileURL path];

 NSFileManager * fileMan = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
 NSArray * files = [fileMan contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:theFolder error:nil];

 if (files)
 {
   for(int index=0;index<files.count;index++)
   {
       NSString * file = [files objectAtIndex:index];


      if (!([file.pathExtension isEqualToString:@"txt"] || [file.pathExtension isEqualToString:@"rtf"] || [file.pathExtension isEqualToString:@"doc"] || [file.pathExtension isEqualToString:@"rtfd"])) {

///alert code
```

Comment: You don't know how to run the alert panel or what is the exact question?

Comment: @Volker No problem with alert panel, sorry ;). Problem is the code above is not properly parsing the folder in question. In other words - the alert panel appears even if the folder in question does contain any of the specified extensions. Am I properly parsing the folder (obviously the lastPathComponent of the path string)??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
NSFileManager * fileMan = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
```

with

```
NSFileManager * fileMan = [[NSFileManager defaultManager];
```

Make sure that

```
NSString *theFolder= [fileURL path];
```

gives you a folder and not a filename!

I would recommend to lowercase all strings in the comparison.

Declare a bool variable outside the for loop like

```
BOOL otherFiles = NO;
if (files) { 
   for(int index=0;index<files.count;index++)
   {
       NSString * file = [files objectAtIndex:index];
       if (!([file.pathExtension.lowercaseString isEqualToString:@"txt"] || 
           [file.pathExtension.lowercaseString isEqualToString:@"rtf"] || 
           [file.pathExtension.lowercaseString isEqualToString:@"doc"] || 
           [file.pathExtension.lowercaseString isEqualToString:@"rtfd"])
       ) otherFiles = YES;
}
if (otherFiles) NSRunAlertPanel.....
```

Make sure that files contains what you expect!